# React Native Expo Can't Find Variable Self

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am suddenly getting this error while creating the new project in expo, when I create any project it loads perfectly and can see the default screen.

When I try to install any dependancy e.g. yarn add native-base it stops working and giving me can't Find Variable Self and Expo gets hanged

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For users creating new project with expo-cli or XDE, you will get red screen “Can’t Find Variable Self” after your first “yarn” or “npm install”. This is because of new “whatwg-fetch” 3.0.0 published yesterday (https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch 23). So you just need to force dependency to previous version: "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
It means put it in package.json as “dependency”. Manually, with “yarn add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4.” Or with “npm add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4”.

Everything should now work like a charm.

Hope this helps ;p

Links:

- [Can't find variable : Self / Can't install firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262184/cant-find-variable-self-cant-install-firebase/52271359#52271359)
- https://forums.expo.io/t/cant-find-variable-self/13547

Up: expo@30.0.1 added whatwg-fetch@2.0.4 as dependency. Problem is gone ;)

Comment: Does this solved for you? I have been developing React Native Apps with Expo since long but i haven't faced this issue till now

Comment: Yes it does. This is because when you start new expo project, there is no package-lock.json or yarn.lock. So last version of whatwg-fetch@3.0.0 is installed. And this version has been published a day ago. I think for now expo still requires whatwg-fetch@2.0.4. This is why you haven't faced this issue yet.

Comment: can you help solve my comment on https://forums.expo.io/t/cant-find-variable-self/13547

Comment: Great! Really thought that some vital modules for my project where out of order, pheww, luckily that wasn't the case.

Comment: @FlorianBonniec may you edit your answer to specify that the right way to do this is to use the `resolutions` field (in case you are using Yarn). Thanks.

Comment: ```expo@30.0.1``` added ```whatwg-fetch@2.0.4``` as dependency. Problem is gone ;)

Comment: @FlorianBonniec I've just created a new expo app using 30.0.1 and my package-lock.json file still had whatwg-fetch@3.0.0. Manually adding 2.0.4 as you said above fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

so the answer to that is

"Yes you have to put it in package.json. Manually, with “yarn add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4.” or with “npm install whatwg-fetch@2.0.4”"

Answer (score 0):

after doing this I get an error "requiring unknown module "985". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run 'yarn', or 'npm install'"
I've done both of these things but still get the error. Anyone see this?

edit: resolved. closed out all of the files and restarted my phone. error went away.

Answer (score 0):

one thing I noticed:
Due to other dependencies it was not sufficient for me to use the newest expo-release. I also had to switch to Yarn (instead of npm).